# Discharging capacitor after power shutdown

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, motor, switches, ac

I've got a simple circuit that acts as a 230V softstart:

[image: ![enter image description here]

It works, but there's one issue with it - after turning it on a 100uF capacitor is charged, and after turning off it is discharged by a 22k resistor.  This 22k resistor is doing it too slow.  It takes some 4 - 5 seconds. When circuit has to be switched on/off/on quickly it basically stops working,

A lower resistance instead of 22k messes up the ramp up time even on the first start, also voltage on out.

Is there is a way to discharge this 100uF (itgets charged up to ~6V) after turning power off by some transistor and resistor?  If so, what transistor could work and how to put it into this circuit?

Here's a wider view:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to soft start? What is your load? Do you have access to a neutral wire (or the other phase)? Or does it have to be an in-line soft starter?

Comment: BTW, I believe your circuit is drawn incorrectly. Or it's not working the way you think it does...

Comment: It works with normal single phase motors, of course there is acces to neutral, 
maybe triac on diagram is incorrectly, I'm not sure.

Comment: This certainly can be done. But with more "active" circuitry. Also, is there anyway you can post the voltage waveform across the motor during start up?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this circuit is just serially connected with motor, but could be in other way if needed, it's important to not add too many elements because it must be small (but 1 small transistor w/ 1 res. wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: Personally, I'd just add another pole to the On-Off switch, so that when in the *off* position, it puts a smaller resistor across the capacitor, perhaps between 100 Ω and 1 kΩ. This would *not* help were the power to be cut elsewhere (e.g., unplugging the device), but would be the simplest way to fix the issue for switched use.

Comment: I can't change or modify switch, but both L and N on both sides of switch can be used.

Comment: There are ICs for discharging X capacitors after power unplug to comply with relevant safety standards. <60 V after 1 s IIRC. Doesn’t burn power when energized yet allows low resistor values for quick discharge. Have you looked into those?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way can be done with a 230 Vac relay, with a normally close contact to discharge capacitor when power is off. Simulation does not agree with your voltage in 100uF capacitor, I get about 90 V in C1, so better use a resistor to limit current through the contact.

[image]

An electronic solution could be with a rectifier, optocoupler and transistors. This is an example with capacitive impedance (C7) and filter (C9) to get a minimum of 6 mA and peak of 24 mA in opto emitter. Transistors should support more than 100 V, according simulation.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this circuit works differently depending on load (its power), also I'm using bt138-600e, voltage on this 100uF was measured right after switching of, not during run, but this is 100uF 25V and he's ok, thanks for these 2 versions